# jQuery UI .draggable "cursor at" variable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

atm I have a div which is draggable. I set the cursor position fixed to a position in the div.

```
//some code
$('#example').draggable({ cursorAt: {
        top: 15,
        left: 200
      }
});
// some more code
```

How is it possible to set the cursorAt to the position wherever the div is "touched" first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You understood this option in the opposite way:

> Sets the offset of the dragging helper **relative to the mouse cursor**. Coordinates can be given as a hash using a combination of one or two keys: { top, left, right, bottom }.

This option is not for positioning the cursor. The cursor position is controlled by the pointing device.

This options is for positioning the helper element which is being dragged relative to cursor, for example positioning its top at the cursor position.

By default the helper will be moved around according to the clicked position (*Not very accurate*). Use this option if you want to put a particular area of element at the cursor position, not the other way.